# Transpose a matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, math, matrix

I need to write a program that transposes a matrix in C. The matrix that needs to be transposed, is a one dimensional array, array A:

```
void fill_array_A(char *arrayA, int ssize)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<ssize; i++)
    {
        printf("Letter %d:\n> ", (i+1));
        scanf(" %c", &arrayA[i]);
    }
}

void show_array_A(char *arrayA, int ssize)
{
    int n = sqrt(ssize);
    int i,j=0;

    for(i=0; i<ssize; i++)
    {
        printf("valueA[%d] = %c ", i, arrayA[i]);

        j ++;

        if(j == n)
        {
            printf("\n");
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}

valueA[0] = a valueA[1] = a valueA[2] = a 
valueA[3] = b valueA[4] = b valueA[5] = b 
valueA[6] = c valueA[7] = c valueA[8] = c
```

I need to transpose the matrix A to matrix B, so B = A(T). B is a two dimensional array, where B stores pointers to elements in array A. However, my code shows wrong results, **instead of**

```
valueB[0] = a valueB[3] = b valueB[6] = c 
valueB[1] = a valueB[4] = b valueB[7] = c 
valueB[2] = a valueB[5] = b valueB[8] = c
```

**my code gives me:**

```
valueB[0] = a valueB[1] = b valueB[2] = b 
valueB[3] = a valueB[4] = b valueB[5] = b 
valueB[6] = a valueB[7] = b valueB[8] = b
```

Where is the problem? Here's the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char* create_array_A(int ssize)
{
    char *arrayA = malloc(sizeof(char) * ssize);
    return arrayA;
}

void fill_array_A(char *arrayA, int ssize)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<ssize; i++)
    {
        printf("Letter %d:\n> ", (i+1));
        scanf(" %c", &arrayA[i]);
    }
}

void show_array_A(char *arrayA, int ssize)
{
    int n = sqrt(ssize);
    int i,j=0;

    for(i=0; i<ssize; i++)
    {
        printf("valueA[%d] = %c ", i, arrayA[i]);

        j ++;

        if(j == n)
        {
            printf("\n");
            j = 0;
        }
    }
}

char** create_array_B(char *arrayA, int ssize)
{
    int n = sqrt(ssize);
    int i,j;

    char **arrayB = malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            arrayB[j] = &arrayA[i];
        }
    }
    return arrayB;
}

void show_array_B(char** arrayB, int n, int m)
{
    int i,j,k=0;

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<m; j++)
        {
            printf("valueB[%d] = %c ", k, arrayB[i][j]);
            k ++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n = 9;

    char *arrayA = create_array_A(n);
    fill_array_A(arrayA, n);
    show_array_A(arrayA, n);

    printf("\n");

    char **arrayB = create_array_B(arrayA, n);
    show_array_B(arrayB, sqrt(n), sqrt(n));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A matrix typically is a 2D array. Transposition of a "vector" is pretty useless, just interpret them differently, depending on their usage. And `char **` is no way a 2D array! A pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code most obvious being the creation of array B. Try it this way:

```
char** create_array_B(char *arrayA, int ssize)
{
    int n = sqrt(ssize);
    int i,j;

    char **arrayB = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ssize);
    //                                      ^^^
    if (arrayB == NULL)
        // handle error
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            arrayB[i * n + j] = &arrayA[j * n + i];
            //     ^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    return arrayB;
}
```

Other errors include printing of elements, memory allocation of bad size, and release/free of the malloced memory missing.

Complete solution can be found [here](https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/c/blob/master/matrix_transp/main.c).

Now everything is fine.  Running above with valgrind:

```
p@:/matrix_transp$ valgrind --leak-check=yes --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./executable 
==30322== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30322== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30322== Using Valgrind-3.10.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30322== Command: ./executable
==30322== 
valueA[0] = 0 valueA[1] = 1 valueA[2] = 2 
valueA[3] = 3 valueA[4] = 4 valueA[5] = 5 
valueA[6] = 6 valueA[7] = 7 valueA[8] = 8 

valueB[0] = 0 valueB[1] = 3 valueB[2] = 6 
valueB[3] = 1 valueB[4] = 4 valueB[5] = 7 
valueB[6] = 2 valueB[7] = 5 valueB[8] = 8 
==30322== 
==30322== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30322==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30322==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 81 bytes allocated
==30322== 
==30322== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30322== 
==30322== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30322== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: ok, thank you very much